# show children of parent like tree view on select menu in symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I created FormClass like this:

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder

          /*.some code.*/

          ->add('parent', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => 'category_name'
          ))

        /*.some code.*/

      ;
    }
```

This load all categories in select menu. but I want to show children of all parent like tree view:

```
Root
- Category1
-- sub_category1
-- sub_category2
--- sub_category1_of_sub_category2
- Category2
-- sub_category3
```

For this, I need recursive function that proccess it.
if EntityType has option similar `query_builder` that give me all result of `class` option, i can solve my problem.

**UPDATE 1**
my table like it:

```
id    |    title                     |    parent

 1         Category1                       Null

 2         sub_category1                     1

 3         sub_category2                     1

 4         sub_category1_of_subcategory2     3

 5         Category2                       Null

 6         sub_category3                     5
```

Comment: is it only 2 level tree?

Comment: no, it's more of 2 level

Comment: Do you have a level property in this Entity?

Comment: no, i count it with recursive function

Comment: @AndrewVakhniuk updated my question

Answer (score 0):

i would recomend you to use [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) for handling tree entity

It will allow you to create tree html elements.

```
  $options = array(
            'decorate' => true,
            'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
            'rootClose' => '</ul>',
            'childOpen' => function ($node) {
                return '<li id="' . $node['id'] . '" class="employee">';
            },
            'childClose' => '</li>',
            'nodeDecorator' => function ($node) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" /><span>' . mb_substr($node['name'],0,1,'utf-8'). '.' . $node['surname'] . '</span>';
            }
        );
        $tree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
            $root, /* starting from root nodes */
            false, /* false: load all children, true: only direct */
            $options,
            true,//include node
            false /*include disabled*/
        );
```